# NULL value checking

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

I am trying to run the following code but the error occurin says you have `error near the @tid.` The parameter is supposed to be taking NULL value.

```
 public static DataTable GetChapterArticlesSummary(long ChapterId, long? TopicId)
{
    DataTable TableArticles = new DataTable();
    try {
        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select Article_Name, Id, Privacy_Term from Articles where Chapter_Id=@chapterid and Topic_Id is @topicid";
            command.Parameters.Add("@chapterid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ChapterId;
            if (TopicId != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@topicid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = TopicId;
            }
            else
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@topicid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            command.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            Adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            Adapter.Fill(TableArticles);
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    { }
    return TableArticles;
}
```

Comment: What's the type and value of `TId`?

Comment: The value I am checking right now is null..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I would handle this:

1. Rewrite the SQL
2. Rewrite the entire code

### 1. Rewrite the SQL

Change the relevant portion of your SQL to this:

```
and (T_Id = @tid or @tid is null)
```

### 2. Rewrite the entire code

This will result in two different SQL statements depending on the parameter (to the code) value:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
if (TId != null)
{
    command.CommandText = "Select Article_Name, Id, Privacy_Term from Articles where Id=@id and T_Id = @tid";
    command.Parameters.Add("@tid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = TId;
}
else
{
    command.CommandText = "Select Article_Name, Id, Privacy_Term from Articles where Id=@id and T_Id is null";
}
command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Id;
command.Connection = connection;
SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
Adapter.SelectCommand = command;
Adapter.Fill(TableArticles);
```

Comment: Ok this is what I guessed too.. but for the value I checked it was null so I thoght it is a problem.

Comment: Sorry I used the @topicid again instead NULL

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in the`if` statement:

```
if (TId != null)
```

In c# a `long` variable is never null, unless you declare it as `long?` so please check with the debugger if its value is correct. If `TId` is not null here, your function will not send `DBNull.Value` to the database.

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls and did you check with the debugger if it goes inside the if?

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls the new code you posted is wrong. You need to use `is` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

try

T_Id = @tid

because you are sending the dbnull.value right.
else debug and check the values of parameters.

Comment: the sql syntax for the null checking is `is` not `=`